# convert paragraph or new elements into checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I have `contenteditable` `div` as **text editor**

Functionality needed is whatever the user writes or copy/paste in text editor turns into checkbox

for eg

> Case 1

If User writes the following

**Test1(enter key pressed)**

**Test2(enter key pressed)**

**Test3(enter key pressed)**

then there should be three checkbox for **Test1**,**Test2**,**Test3** respectively

And

> Case2

when the user writes

Parent1 (enter key pressed)

- Test1(enter key pressed)
- Test2(enter key pressed)
- Test3(enter key pressed)

In the above case there will be 4 checkbox `parent1` and 3 `li's`

Things i have achieved but i am open to accept new way if more accurate.

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
var $p = "";  
     var re = /\S/;
     $p = $('.outputBox');
      $p.contents()
      .filter(function() {    
        return this.nodeType == 3&& re.test(this.nodeValue);;  
     })
    .wrap('<label> <input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on" />')
});
```

**[FIDDLE Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/wLrfqvss/4/)**

Basically a new span,div,br tags or for that matter li's should be created into checkboxes.

If there is any different method which will fulfill both the requirement/basic requirement of creating checkboxes it is most welcome.

Comment: In Case2, you want to create the `li` elements on detecting tab key???

Comment: on click on any button..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everybody has given answer to first case of question but i found answer for 2nd case
i added this two lines in the click event of  **SHOW CONTENT with CHECKBOX**

I guess @arthi sreekumar is also getting me `li's` into `checkbox` Upvote to that.

```
 $('.outputBox').find("ol").find("li").wrapInner(('<label style="display:block;"> <input type="checkbox" class="liolChk" name="field_1" value="on" />')); 
 $('.outputBox').find("ul").find("li").wrapInner(('<label style="display:block;"> <input type="checkbox" class="liolChk" name="field_1" value="on" />'));
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/wLrfqvss/10/)**

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution. I have made a traversal to the innermost text element and then convert that into a checkbox.

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {
     var $p = "";  
     $p = $('.outputBox');
     wrapText($p);
});

function wrapText(domObj) {
    var re = /\S/;
    domObj.contents().filter(function() {
        if (this.nodeType === 1) {
            wrapText($(this));
        } else {
            return (this.nodeType === 3 && re.test(this.nodeValue));
         }
    })
    .wrap('<label> <input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on" /></label>');
}
```

Here is the fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/wLrfqvss/6/

Hope thats what you are looking for.

If you want this to happen for only certain elements, you could always add a check like so:

```
if (this.nodeType === 1 && this.tagName === 'DIV')
```

in the above code.

Comment: I didnt modify any of the code you had given. Just wrote the logic for creating checkboxes. Are you facing a problem with the input box as well?

Answer (score 1):

you can use template for checkbox instead of hardcoding html

```
<div id="template" style="visibility:hidden">
<label> <input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on" /></label>
</div>
```

in code

```
$('#checkbox').click(function() {});

 function createElement()
{
 var targetElement=$("#template").clone(true);
 targetElement.removeAttr("style");
 targetElement.attr("name","new id");
 var $p = "";  
 var re = /\S/;
 $p = $('.outputBox');
  $p.contents()
  .filter(function() {    
    return this.nodeType == 3&& re.test(this.nodeValue);;  
 })
.wrap(targetElement)
}
```

this will also provide you flexibility of using any html template as the code is not control specific

Answer (score 0):

How about using `*(space)` to generate `li`? I used regex and process string to generate it.

```
function update() {
    var str = $('#inputBox').html();
    $('#outputBox').html(str);
    $('#showHTML').text(str);

    str = str.replace(/(<br>$)/,'')
             .replace(/(<br>)/g,'$1\n')
             .replace(/\* (.*)/g, '<li>$1</li>')
             .replace(/^(?!<li>)/gm,'<input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on">')
             .replace(/^<li>(.*)<\/li>/gm,'<li><input type="checkbox" name="field_1" value="on">$1</li>');

    if(str.indexOf('<li>')!=-1) {
        var index = str.indexOf('<li>');
        var lastIndex; 
        str = str.substring(0, index) + '<ul>' + str.substring(index);        
        lastIndex = str.lastIndexOf('</li>') +  '</li>'.length+  1;
        str = str.substring(0, lastIndex) + '</ul>' + str.substring(lastIndex);
    }
    $('#translatedBox').html(str);
    $('#translatedHTML').text(str);
}
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ssk7833/8f04wawy/6/)

Comment: there are blank checkbox added as enter key is pressed

Comment: Updated. Please check jsfiddle again.

Comment: i dont see any change even now there are blank checkbox on enter key pressed in between of any word

Comment: In previous version, when you pressed enter in any line, it would generate a <br> in last line. This version will not add <br> in last line. What the result do you expect? I'm confused now.  What do you expect when a line is blank?

Answer (score 0):

Hello I change your js code as follow,

```
$('div[contenteditable=true]').blur(function() {



    $('.outputBox').append('<br>').append("<input type='checkbox' value='"+$(this).html()+"' />"+$(this).html());
$(this).html("");

 });




$('div[contenteditable=true]').keydown(function(e) {
    //$('.outputBox').html($(this).html()); i commented this line
```

I hope its working something like you were looking for..